# Auto exclude (-externs) option cannot be marked

Tags: eclipse, extern, swc, fdt

I have an swc file that I want to compile as external in a flex project.

I use eclipse FDT 5.

i read that I need do `Source -> Remove from Export' on that swc file and besides that under the 'FDT Compiler' properties section I need to mark 'Auto exclude (-externs)'. the problem is that when I mark it and press OK it doesn't get saved and when I get back to the properties page I see it as not marked.

any ideas how to resolve the issue ? is there another way to achieve this ?

i noticed that the file  .settings/com.powerflasher.fdt.core.prefs contains compilation options.
is there a way to add this option manually to the prefs file ? for now I need to use a script to manually compile my project until this issue is resolved.

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots or perhaps some more info. Are you talking about marking libraries (.SWCs) as Runtime Share Libraries. It sounds like you're using Project References to share code correct? That is what 'Remove from Export' is for.  Are you perhaps JUST trying to compile a .SWC?

Comment: Remove from export is not enough. I also need to mark 'Auto Exclude' because i want the compiler to add that swc file as extern and without marking this option the swc file is just ignored in compilation

Answer (score 1):

For each swc add the compile argument

```
-external-library-path+="path/to/library.swc"
```

If all the swcs are in the same folder then you can just add the path to that folder.
If you're using Windows I think you still need to use forward slashes.